# How do I fix this error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I want to sort the results of a list of data according to sort critera selected by a user from a dropdown list and I'm getting this error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I've read through many posts on this site with a similar question but my understanding isn't good enough yet to relate the solutions i've found to my specific problem.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error in this instance and how to fix it?

**My Html View**

```
        @Html.DropDownList("SortParm", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(),
            new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
        < script >
        function CallChangefunc(sortKey) {
        window.location.href = "/dashboard/Report_Performance?id=" + sortKey;
        }
        </ script >
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report_Performance(string id, string sortKey)
{
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
    if (id != null)
        newDate = DateTime.Parse(id);
    var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, newDate);
    aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderByDescending<>;    //<- PROBLEM IS HERE
    ViewBag.SelectedItem = id;
    ViewBag.SortParm = sortKey;
    return this.View(aVar);
}
```

I tried each of these statements in the controller with no success:

```
        //aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy<>;
        //aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy<sortKey>;
        //aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy < Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, sortKey);
        //aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderByDescending<>;
```

Comment: Are you able to get data in **aVar** ?

Comment: Yes. the declaration statement for aVar gets data.

Comment: What is the type of aVar? Or ...what is the return type of GetStats?

Comment: Since aVar is not strongly typed, I believe it's variant. GetStats returns a list of data rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, newDate);
aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderByDescending(x=>x.sortKey);
```

as you fatch data in aVar variable which have a list of stats(aVar.CurrentListingStats),after that when you apply sorting on that using lembda expression so in Linq Expression require a parameter that on which key value data will be sorted show we need to provide a column name to sort data.

as in above question user use this like a statement not as method

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you for taking me in the right direction. Per your suggestion I did some reading up on lembda and Linq and came up with the following code that works:  aVar.CurrentListingStats = aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy(i => i.Make).ToList();